# Page load status and calling it once. [javascript]

Tags: javascript, function

So I made a function that displays page loading process in the console.

```
    var processLoader = 1;
    var processesToLoadInTotal = 14;
    var progressBarFill = "";
    function processBar(msg) {
        // console.clear();
        var procent = Math.floor((processLoader / processesToLoadInTotal)*100);
        if (procent >= 100) {
            console.info("%cFully loaded.", "border-radius: 5px;background-color: green; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;");
        } else {
            processLoader++;
            progressBarFill += " ";
            var progressBarEmpty = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < processesToLoadInTotal - processLoader; i++) {
                progressBarEmpty += " ";
            }
            console.info("%c"+progressBarFill+"%c"+progressBarEmpty, "border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;background-color: #6cf; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;","border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;");
            console.info(procent + "% "+ msg);
        }
    }
    processBar("Loaded page.")
```

So my idea was to have a loading bar in the console and that works. I call the function at 14 points across my project but my problem is that I have an event listener at one point for button press. When I press the button the final processBar is called again. So I have two problems:

1. Is there a way to collect automatically the processesToLoadTotal (how many times the function will execute or I must specify it manually?
2. Can I call a function once on a given row? Maybe an array of some sort?

P.S.: I don't have any exp in javascript. And I don't use jQuery for this project and I intend to keep it that way.

Thank you

Comment: try using `setInterval` - calls a function every time interval, both passed as `setInterval` parameters.  Then explicit calls are not necessary. Read some docs; `setInterval` returns a process ID and you need that to kill the process when done.

Comment: You should always check if console exists prior to using it.  Some browsers stop processing script when the console window is not open.  Example:`window.console && window.console.info("hi");`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss where should I add this check could you suggest in the second existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a different approach. While I was adding time stamps in the console I made another if else where I do nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dev = false;
    var processLoader = 1;
    var processesToLoadInTotal = 14;
    var y = 1;
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < processesToLoadInTotal; i++) {
        names[i] = "Точка "+y;
        y++;
    }
    var progressBarFill = "";
    function processBar(msg) {
        if (dev) {
            if (processLoader != 1) {
                console.timeEnd(names[processLoader-2]);
            }
            console.time(names[processLoader-1]);
        } else {
            console.clear();
        }
        var percent = Math.floor((processLoader / processesToLoadInTotal)*100);
        if (percent == 100) {
            console.info("%cFully loaded.", "border-radius: 5px;background-color: green; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;");
            console.warn("%c Нещо не си взима правилно window.innerWidth. core.js ред: 16. Оказа се, че е само на firefox... core.js:15", "font-size: 16px");
            processLoader++;
        } else if (percent > 100) {

        } else {
            processLoader++;
            progressBarFill += " ";
            var progressBarEmpty = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < processesToLoadInTotal - processLoader; i++) {
                progressBarEmpty += " ";
            }
            console.info("%c"+progressBarFill+"%c"+progressBarEmpty, "border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;background-color: #6cf; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;","border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px;");
            console.info(percent + "% "+ msg);
        }
    }
    processBar("Loading head includes.")
    </script>
```

Comment: This will fail as soon as `console.info(procent + "% "+ msg);` is hit because `procent` is undefined,  a typo I assume.

Comment: Yes. In my native language is procent but then I edited it for here so it's understandable. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe there is no workaround for this unfortunately. You must define the number of things that must be loaded unless the number of things that is to be loaded is based on an external source. *eg. call function number of times for number of clients*
2. yes this is entirely doable

   ```
   var rows = [0, 1, 2];

   var count = 0;

   var interval = setInterval(function() {

       // stop looping once you've done all of your rows
       if(count++ == rows.length) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       }
       else {
       // increment your bar here
       }
   }, /* time to loop in ms */);
   ```